# How do I use LinqPad for updates with CRM 2011

Tags: linq

I am working with linqpad and crm 2011, cloud version, and C# snippets.  Simple select queries work as advertised.  Nonetheless for linqpad to be of any real use I need to get it to do updates and inserts as well and have not been able to find sample code which works or come up with any real information.  Several kinds of things which show up in sample code I see around the net are missing.  in particular, TestDataContext appears to be part of one or more assemblies which get loaded with linq-sql projects in Visual Studio, but is not in evidence on linqpad.  SubmitChanges is not there, and it is not clear what I'd have to do to get at it or to instantiate a new DataContext object and try to use its submitchanges method.

Any usable information would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't know the CRM 2011 LINQ implementation. Does LINQPad have direct support for that?

Anyway, you basically can run any C# code in LINQPad. Here's a step-by-step guide how to run the needed code:

1. You need to add the required framework assemblies (maybe take a look at your Visual Studio project). To achieve this, go to the ‘Query’->’Advanced Query Properties’. On the dialog, click on ‘Add…’, then on ‘Browse…’. Browse to the assemblies. Add the required assemblies. Keep the ‘Advanced Query Properties’-dialog open for the next step. Optinally add your own assemblies when you use types from it.
2. In the ‘Advanced Query Properties’-dialog go the tab ‘Additional Namespace Imports’. Add there the namespaces you need. Expecially the LINQ-namespaces of your LINQ-provider.
3. Click on ‘Set as default for new queries’ so that you don’t need to repeat the three steps above next time. Then we’re done.
4. Now you can use the LINQ-provider in LINQ-Pad. Use the 'C#-Statements'-language. Use the .Dump-method to view query results.

Now with that steps you can use any API in LINQPad. With that you can do loops and use the regular API to update objects.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me in Linqpad for CRM.

Remember that the context is implied in Linqpad.

Create your new entity and load its data, then:

```
AddObject(entityName);
SaveChanges();
```